# Multiple YouTubePlayerViews within one Activity

Tags: android, api, youtube

I have an activity that can create multiple YouTubePlayerViews programmatically, here's the class containing each YouTubePlayerView.

```
public class MyYouTubeView extends LinearLayout implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private String mYouTubeVideoId;
private YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;

public JournalYouTubeView(Activity context, String youTubeVideoId) {
    super(context);
    mYouTubeVideoId = youTubeVideoId;
    String apiKey = context.getResources().getString(R.string.youtube_api_key);
    mYouTubePlayerView = new YouTubePlayerView(context);
    mYouTubePlayerView.setTag(mYouTubeVideoId);
    mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(apiKey, this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int margin = (int) ScreenUtils.dip2pixel(10, context);
    params.leftMargin = margin;
    params.rightMargin = margin;
    addView(mYouTubePlayerView, params);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        final YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {

    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(mYouTubeVideoId);
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when I have multiple instances of the YouTubePlayerView in my view hierarchy. In the sample API apps they seem to use Fragments when dealing with multiple videos however I can't use those without some major re-engineering of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems (although not mentioned in docs) that you can only host one video player per activity. The solution is to use ThumbNailViews which will launch one YouTubePlayerView.